# Crashing When knitting R Markdown under Linux

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, R Version: 3.4.3, R Studio: Version 1.1.383*

I'm playing around and learning R Markdown this afternoon. I am *not* doing any intensive data analysis. I am knitting my R Markdown into HTML with the following command `rmarkdown::render("document.Rmd")`.

About every half an hour my Ubuntu GNOME session almost totally freezes. I can sort of move the mouse cursor around and every several minutes I'm presented with a brief window of time where the computer works again before going back into a deep freeze. I'm not running anything other programs.

I've kept my *System Monitor* open and notice that rsession and rstudio usually utilize ~200 MiB of memory. When the computer freezes the rsession rises to ~4 GiB and it's also directly after I issue the `rmarkdown::render("document.Rmd")` command in R Studio.

I did sudo-apt-update and sudo-apt-upgrade. What else should I do? Do I update the Linux kernel? Upgrade R Studio? Submit a bug report? Is this a memory leak (and what is that)?

Comment: `1.1.383` had known unresponsive/freezing problems on both Windows and Linux. You can try the [Preview](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) or [Daily build](https://dailies.rstudio.com/) to see if the problem goes away

Comment: `1.1.423` and still having the same issue. Reluctantly going to try Visual Studio R version.

Comment: File an issue here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues. Make sure to include the Rmd file that you're using

Comment: Have you tried daily build yet? It's v1.2.405 as of Mar 11